# Spotify without Redirect URI?

Tags: python, spotify

I'm using Spotipy to get some spotify data from an authorized user but I can't understand how to authorize my account.

Am I correct in thinking that a server is required that hosts something at http://www.myapp.com/callback ? What needs to be returned? Maybe I'm completely missing something here... I'm very confused by the whole required redirect URI thing...

I am trying to make a program, without website, so how should I handle authorization? What exactly should the redirect URI do?

Thanks

Edit:

Using http://localhost:8888/callback as my redirect URI now and that works. I'm not even sure why since nothing is running on that port.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about Spotify's API. But I have worked with similar APIs in the past (or even designed them). What I assume is that they use some kind of OpenID/OAuth authorization mechanism.

The very nature of these APIs is that they work through the browser! The idea is that MyApp doesn't have your *actual* Spotify credentials, but instead some signed token it can use.

To communicate this token to the MyApp, there are the server-callbacks, outlined in your question. Because all the browser can do is to redirect to a special URL you provide, with some info added.

So there are conceptually two ways to deal with this:

- the easy, server-based one: you in fact register a myapp.com. When your app tries to authorize with spotify, it first creates a unique resource (myapp.com/authrequests/HASH-NUMBER), and communicates this as callback. Then it goes through the  motions of making spotify authorize it, and once these are finished, there will have been a call to myapp.com/authrequests/HASH-NUMBER/ADDITIONAL-INFO. So while your app is waiting for this to happen, it has to poll (or open a websocket and listen to that) myapp.com. Complicated? Wait, it gets better!
- the harder, OS-dependent one: you write an application that registers itself as protocol-provider with your browsers. E.g. my company does that with the protocol "ableton". Thus we can make the browser generate "ableton://AUTHORIZATION-REQUEST-RESULT" URLs which will then be communicated through Browser and OS to the running application, and thus you receive the necessary secret.

HTH

Comment: I'm using Spotipy and I believe it does the listening already (and opens the browser to authorize) but the part I don't get is the URI. Do I have to point it at my own domain? If I do, what does the callback need to return? Or can I just use a non existing URI?

Comment: It's [this](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy) python project. But I've solved it for now, see my original post edit. Thanks for the explanation though.